# batch file execution of jar error - Could not find the main class

Tags: batch-file, jar, execution

My intent is to give a batch file that executes a jar of a java application/tool to functional analysts team who do not know java. When I execute the batch file, I get the below error. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

How to debug to find out if the issues is in main() which takes care of loading log4j and config files?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: x.y.XYZClass           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: x.y.XYZClass        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: x.y.XYZClass
.  Program will exit.
```

This what I did so far:
I packaged an application using Maven with the following directory structure:

```
bin/run.bat
lib/application.jar and other jars that it depends on
config.properties
log4j.xml
```

jar manifest file content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: 
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_20
Main-Class: x.y.XYZClass
Class-Path: vn.jar pn.jar
```

run.bat content:

```
java -cp .;../lib/application.jar x.y.XYZClass -Dconfig.properties.name=../config.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=../log4j.xml
```

I execute run.bat from command line from bin folder.

XYZClass main() does the following:
loads log4j.xml and config.properties and does other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the XYZClass exists inside application.jar, in the correct directory.  From the bin directory, run the command:

`jar tvf ../lib/application.jar`.

The output should resemble:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
x/
x/y/
x/y/XYZClass.class
```

Also, since you've created an executable jar (by specifying Main-Class in your manifest), you should be able to run it with: `java -jar ..\lib\application.jar`